# How to restore truncated MySQL table from binary logs?

Tags: mysql, restore, recovery, logs, mysqlbinlog

I have a mysql server and while working on it I accidentlly truncated the wrong table. I do have a mysql dump wich I immediately used to restore my database structure, but I still miss some entries in only one table.

SHOW BINARY LOGS shows me 64 logs.

How do I know wich log to restore and what is the procedure of restoring with mysqlbinlog? Using the last log is not changing anything ...

EDIT: I already checked http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html  but didn't accomplish anything

Would it be enough to just manually search all logs for the needed insert statements?

Thank you
Soda

Answer (score 1):

You can restore the database from binary logs only if they were enables from the very beginning and if there are all of them starting from `.00001`.

Then to restore the database you need to replay all binlogs on a fresh MySQL instance:

```
for log in mysql-bin.*
do
    mysqlbinlog $log | mysql -h <destination host>
done
```

If you truncated a table you probably need to restore just it. Then restore the database on some other host and move the table to the original server.